# Database design - performance

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm designing a database for a club. There is a "member" entity that practices activities (sports, etc.). These activities have different categories according to the age of the member. Each activity in its respective category will have schedules. In turn, the members will have their own schedules, because, for example they could attend only 2 days of an activity that takes place 4 days within a week.
I solved it like this:

https://ibb.co/dsJkHz

My question is: Is this a viable method for solving this problem? I seems a bit complicated and I don't think it's ideal/optimized for performance. I'm sure there must be another way. Thanks!

Comment: well, first you'd have to define "okay" in a lot more detail. It looks like it models the comparatively vague requirements for structure which you've given us. As far as I can tell it's correctly normalised. Why do you think it's complicated? How do you propose to simplify it? As for performance, that's generally reliant on a much bigger set of factors than just the schema. A correctly normalised schema will help though, of course.

Comment: I think the table relationship is good.  It's normalized correctly.  I don't think it's complicated.

Comment: Well, another option was to use a "category" attribute in the "activity" table, but it did not seem like a viable solution. I said it would be complicated, thinking about the time to develop a Rest API with spring boot and jpa. It must be because I lack experience with large databases

Comment: this is not a large database! In terms of the number of tables, it's tiny. As for a REST API, it could be anything. The operations it exposes don't necessarily have to exactly match the tables, if that doesn't make sense for the business requirements.

Comment: "Another option was to use a "category" attribute in the "activity" table". That would be fine if each activity can only ever belong to one category. If that meets your requirement, then it would be a valid simplification. We can't make that decision for you, it depends on what the current (and any anticipated future) business requirements are.

Answer (score 0):

Performance will be fine as long as you have indexes on the id columns that will be searched or joined on. The other option is enums in some places to limit the joins which you can get away with if there are 4 categories that will not change or rarely ever change but it looks like you're trying to follow best practices and plan for the future.
Your schema is based on categories and activities wanting to use a set list but that list can grow or names can change so they have their own table and from what I can tell the other tables are required for a one to many relationship so even though other options are available they seem like a bad route to take.